# Drag and Drop isn't working?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I tried all methods (setting grid background to transparent etc.) I can't get it to work.

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,-9" Background="Transparent">

    <ListBox x:Name="PlaylistBox" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Height="358" Margin="19,274,0,0" Width="299" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0" 
             Foreground="White" Background="Black" 
             SelectionChanged="PlaylistBox_SelectionChanged" 
             MouseDoubleClick="PlaylistBox_MouseDoubleClick" 
             AllowDrop="True"  
             Drop="PlaylistBox_Drop"/>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a better clarification of what "isn't working"? Is it that your "Drop" method is not executing? Or are you getting errors? "Isn't working" is very broad and I am not sure what your expected behavior is. And what are you dragging?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `PlaylistBox_Drop` does it get hit? Do you get the "drop" cursor when you drag something over your listbox? *"It does nothing"* is also not very helpful when debugging because there are many reasons that could be causing that... we need to know specifics about exactly what isn't working, and at what point in the code something isn't working as expected.

Comment: I have strikethrough cursor. It's not executing PlaylistBox_Drop. I tried admin privigles too.

Comment: I also tried copy ready listBox from drag'n'drop example and it's not working too.

Comment: could you add some code showing what you are trying to drag into the listbox?

Comment: WTF?! I tried VS 2013 (I have 2015) and it's working. -.-

Comment: Sounds like it might be a permissions issue then... If I recall correctly, newer versions of windows or visual studio run with tighter security, which could be what is causing the behavior. Maybe something like [this](http://superuser.com/q/59051/50337), which reads Windows Explorer as "normal user", but "Visual Studio" as "Admin user", so it prevents dragging items from normalUser to adminUser applications.

Comment: Yeah, it was solution. Anyway thank you! :-)